# Use the setter with an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony

My problem is this: I am developing the security of my website. In my user registration form I have five fields: 1) Name 2 ) email 3) Password 4) isActive 5) role. Obviously I don't want the last two items visible in the form, because otherwise violate my security expectations.

Therefore, the item "isActive" I put one with the setter, but the role is an array and if I get the following: `$user-> setRoles('ROLE_USER')` is not working.

I got this error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of
>   the type array, string given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavoc\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 547 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavoc\vendor\doctrine\collections\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php
>   line 47

Here is my code:

```
 public function registroAction()
{
    $peticion = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = new User();
    $role = new Role();
    $role->addRole(array('ROLE_USER')); //it does not work
    $user->setRoles($role);  // User relate with Role
    $formulario = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);


    if ($peticion->getMethod() == 'POST') 
    {
        $formulario->submit($peticion);

        if ($formulario->isValid()) {
        $encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
        $user->setSalt(md5(time()));
        $passwordCodificado = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt() );
        $user->setPassword($passwordCodificado);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('usuario_registro'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render( 'ProyectoSeguridadBundle:Seguridad:registro.html.twig',
    array('formulario' => $formulario->createView())
    );
}
```

**Here is my User model:**

```
    <?php

namespace Proyecto\SeguridadBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
* Proyecto\SeguridadBundle\Entity\User
*
* @ORM\Table(name="lavoc_users")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proyecto\SeguridadBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
*/
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;


    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=25, unique=true )
    */
    private $username;


    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=32)
    */
    private $salt;


    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=64)
    */
    private $password;


    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=60, unique=true)
    */
    private $email;


    /**
    * @var boolean
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean")
    */
    private $isActive;



    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
    *
    */
    private $roles;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));

    }


    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
    * Set username
    *
    * @param string $username
    * @return User
    */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
    * @inheritDoc
    */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }


    /**
    * Set salt
    *
    * @param string $salt
    * @return User
    */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
    * @inheritDoc
    */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }


    /**
    * Set password
    *
    * @param string $password
    * @return User
    */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
    * @inheritDoc
    */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }


    /**
    * Set email
    *
    * @param string $email
    * @return User
    */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
    * Get email
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }


    /**
    * Set isActive
    *
    * @param boolean $isActive
    * @return User
    */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
    * Get isActive
    *
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }


    /**
    * @inheritDoc
    */
    public function getRoles()
    {

        $roles = array();
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            $roles[] = $role->getRole();
        }

        return $roles;
    }


    /**
    * @inheritDoc
    */
    public function eraseCredentials() {
    }


    /**
    * @see \Serializable::serialize()
    */
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array($this->id,));
    }


    /**
    * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
    */
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list ($this->id,) = unserialize($serialized);
    }


    public function isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    public function isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }


    public function isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    public function isEnabled() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }


    /**
    * Set roles
    *
    * @param string $roles
    * @return User
    */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
        return $this;
    }


}
```

**My Role.php**

```
<?php
namespace Proyecto\SeguridadBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
* Role
*
* @ORM\Table(name="lavoc_roles")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proyecto\SeguridadBundle\Entity\RoleRepository")
*/
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
    */
    private $name;
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
    */
    private $role;
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
    */
    private $users;
    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
    return $this->id;
    }
    /**
    * Set name
    *
    * @param string $name
    * @return Role
    */
    public function setName($name)
    {
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
    }
    /**
    * Get name
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getName()
    {
    return $this->name;
    }
    /**
    * Set role
    *
    * @param string $role
    * @return Role
    */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
    $this->role = $role;
    return $this;
    }
    /**
    * @see RoleInterface
    */
    public function getRole()
    {
    return $this->role;
    }
    /**
    * Set users
    *
    * @param string $users
    * @return Role
    */
    public function setUsers($users)
    {
    $this->users = $users;
    return $this;
    }
    /**
    * Get users
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getUsers()
    {
    return $this->users;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
    return $this->getName().' '.$this->getRole();
    }

    /**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param \Seguridad\Entity\Role $roles
     */
    public function addRole(\MyBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * Remove roles
     *
     * @param \SeguridadBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     */
    public function removeRole(\MyBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
        $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `$user->setRoles('ROLE_USER')`, you try to add an `string` into a `ArrayCollection`. That's why you have an `ArrayCollection` exception.

Can you try to add this code (make sure to replace `\MyBundle\Entity\Role` by your own `Role` model)

```
/**
 * Add roles
 *
 * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Role $roles
 */
public function addRole(\MyBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
    $this->roles[] = $roles;
}

/**
 * Remove roles
 *
 * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Role $roles
 */
public function removeRole(\MyBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
    $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
}

/**
* @inheritDoc
*/
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

To use it, you need to pass an `Role` object to the `addRole` or `removeRole` methods.

***Other information***

If you want define a default value for `isActive` and/or other values, you can just  call the appropriate setter in the `constructor` of your `User` model.

Example:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // your own logic
    $this->isActive = true;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hello such , it seems very logical that you raised me and implement it in my code. The setter isActive works well and gives me the true isActive successfully. But I get an error regarding these roles: ContextErrorException: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavoc\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1375

Comment: Can you show us the code of your `User` model ? please

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: I implemented what you raised me but not as done in the driver 's role is ROLE_USER . Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

role is an ArrayCollection, so you can not replace it with a string,

you should add a function like this

```
public function addRoles($role)
{
    $this->roles[] = $role;
    return $this
}
```

and use addRole instead() of setRoles()

Comment: I implemented what you raised me but not as done in the driver 's role is ROLE_USER . Can you help me?

Comment: in the code of the other answer they type the parameter with your entity "\MyBundle\Entity\Role", it means that you have to pass an Role object to this addRoles() function, so you have to get the entity of ROLE_USER and then add it to your arraycollection

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `addRole(Role $role)` method instead.

See [establishing association in Doctine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations).

```
public function addRole(Role $role)
{ 
    $this->roles->add($role);
}
```

Or with check if role exists:

```
public function addRole(Role $role)
{ 
    if (!$this->roles->contains($role)) {
        $this->roles->add($role);
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented what you raised me but not as done in the driver 's role is ROLE_USER . Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand you comment. Could you update the code in your question and the error you get?